# How To Count All Operands And Operators in a Java File

Tags: java, file, operators, lexical-analysis, operands

I have a java file and i want to count the number of binary,unary,logical operators,and operands in it.I just know  i need to use regex for it and i know the basic of it.The task might be simple but  what i can't figure out is  that there are comment lines, so I dont know how to do this exactly.
For example suppose i read a .java file into a EXAMPLE_TEST string;(first line1 has been read and processed in the code, after line2 has been read and processed.To keep it simple, I'm not writing the file reading part.)For line 1 output would be 2 ,but for line 2 output will be a number that unexpected because it is in the comment section.Can you show me a way to do this I'm just a beginner in java and stuck.

```
 int counter=0;
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+-*%]");  
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
      
        while (matcher.find()) {
            
            System.out.println(matcher.group());/*print what have found in string between (+-*%)   */
           counter++;
        }
       System.out.println(counter);//print the number of operators found
```

content of .java file example:
/* line1 is between comment lines */

/* a=a+4 ;   b++; */

/* line2 is not between comment lines */

b=b+8 ;   c=d%10;

Comment: Are you trying to support comments that go across lines?  This is not likely to be an easy problem, though it might be manageable depending on the problem constraints.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm talking about the operators inside the comment, because they are in the comments, they should not be included in the Total number of operators or operands.

Comment: FYI: http://JavaParser.org/ or [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)

Comment: The JFlex manual starts with [an example](https://jflex.de/manual.html#ExampleUserCode) which could easily be modified to add the additional operators you need to count.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job entirely. Don't try this. You will need a Java-compliant lexer and grammar, such as come with JavaCC.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is probably going to be to process the entire file with regexes to remove comments entirely -- to get an entire new version of the file -- and *then* to scan for operators.

Comment: I also think so ,thanks.I did not get why this answer get downvote is there something wrong in it

Comment: Probably because if you really want something that'll guarantee it works for every Java file, you can't use regexes at all, you have to use a full Java parser.  I _do_ think this will be adequate for beginner use cases, though.

Comment: (I had the same reaction at first, but for sanely built files this should work perfectly fine.)